# Simple jQuery Code For Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

hopefully one of you can help me. I have this simple jQuery code and everything works but I just want to modify this code so that it only executes when a person clicks on "Add To Cart".

Here is the link to the shopify theme I'm using: https://venture-theme-snowboards.myshopify.com/collections/snowboards/products/dc-mens-tone-snowboard-2015

Here is the code i'm using:

```html
<script>
    window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);
    function redirectCheckout(){
  if(!(window.location.href.includes("?1"))){
    window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/checkout";
  }
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much apperciated!

Comment: Do you have the access to Theme's Liquid Files?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

Add onClick attribute to call the function on `Add to Cart` button. This is the same for all pages, I have checked.

```
<button type="submit" name="add" onclick="getRedirect()" id="AddToCart-product-template" class="btn btn--full product-form__cart-submit">
      <span id="AddToCartText-product-template">

          Add to Cart

      </span>
</button>
```

Then define your javascript code as a function:

```
<script>
    function getRedirect(){ 

       window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);
        function redirectCheckout(){
      if(!(window.location.href.includes("?1"))){
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/checkout";
      }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Himanshu I tried your code and it seems to work but there is one small problem. They way my site works is when I add a product to the cart, it refreshes 1 time. Therefore it will not register the "click" because of this refresh. Do you think there would be a work around to this?

Comment: ok, so in which case, you want to redirect the user? Before the pare refresh or after it ?

Comment: Actually I want to redirect the user after the refresh, After a few hours of tinkering I thought of a solution, by utilizing `<span class="site-header__cart-indicator "></span>` meaning if you can set your code to only execute when `<span class="site-header__cart-indicator "></span>`  is present on page load, this would fix the issue because "site-header__cart-indicator " only appears after the refresh in the source code of the page.